# What are the effects debezium has on the source dataBase?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, debezium, mysqlbinlog

In the official website on FAQ ([debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/faq/#how_does_debezium_affect_source_databases)) it is mentioned that there are effects of Debezium on source DB. I am looking for the exact what are effects and their consequences?

Comment: The documentation explicitly tells that "MySQL server must be configured to use the row-level binlog". I.e. you cannot use statement-based or mixed binary logging. This may be inconvenient or even impossible.

Comment: I am more curious to know why there is a performance difference in setting up the Debezium in master  other than setting Debezium in replica